# Status 404 returned while using httr::POST() on Microsoft Text Analysis API

Tags: r, httr

I am trying to use the Microsoft Cognitive APIs through `R` to process text data. I have created an account and acquired the key. The code is as follows. I have not included the key for privacy reasons.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

cogapikey <- "xxxx"
cogapi <- "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0"
text=c("is this english?"
       ,"tak er der mere kage"
       ,"merci beaucoup"
       ,"guten morgen"
       ,"bonjour"
       ,"merde"
       ,"That's terrible"
       ,"R is awesome")
df <- data_frame(id=1:length(text),text)
mydata<- list(documents=df)

# language detection
## construct a request
response <- POST(cogapi,add_headers(`Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`=cogapikey),
                 body=toJSON(mydata))
print(response)
```

Upon printing the response variable, I get the following.

```
Response [https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0]
  Date: 2017-11-04 13:29
  Status: 404
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 54 B
```

I am trying to replicate the tutorial given [here](https://itsalocke.com/blog/r-quick-tip-microsoft-cognitive-services-text-analytics-api/).
My session information is as follows

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.8      bitops_1.0-6        dplyr_0.7.4         data.table_1.10.4-3 jsonlite_1.5       
[6] httr_1.3.1          tm_0.7-1            NLP_0.1-11          tidytext_0.1.4     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13      compiler_3.4.0    plyr_1.8.4        bindr_0.1         tokenizers_0.1.4  tools_3.4.0      
 [7] tibble_1.3.4      nlme_3.1-131      lattice_0.20-35   pkgconfig_2.0.1   rlang_0.1.2       Matrix_1.2-9     
[13] psych_1.7.8       curl_3.0          parallel_3.4.0    bindrcpp_0.2      janeaustenr_0.1.5 stringr_1.2.0    
[19] grid_3.4.0        glue_1.2.0        R6_2.2.2          foreign_0.8-67    reshape2_1.4.2    tidyr_0.7.2      
[25] purrr_0.2.4       magrittr_1.5      SnowballC_0.5.1   assertthat_0.2.0  mnormt_1.5-5      stringi_1.1.5    
[31] slam_0.1-40       broom_0.4.2
```

I was wondering if there is an additional prerequisite tool/package I should install? Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Seems the endpoint needs correction here. It should be:

```
cogapi <- "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/languages"
```

**/langauges** is missing in the endpoint.